# Normed algebras of indefinite signature?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

[Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)) states that a real possibly-non-associative algebra (meaning just a real vector space $V$ equipped with a map $m: V \otimes V \to V$) along with a *positive definite* quadratic form $|\cdot|^2 : V \to \mathbb R$ which is multiplicative (in the sense that $|m(v,w)|^2 = |v|^2 |w|^2$) is necessarily one of the algebras $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb H$, or $\mathbb O$.

What happens when positive definiteness is dropped?  (To make the question nontrival, let's demand that the associated symmetric pairing on $V$ is nondegenerate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to my question is that these are called [composition algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra) and are essentially fully understood.  I was hoping the answer would be more interesting.

Comment: Except for triality business I would say :D

Comment: ...well also in the one open case of nontrivial Kervaire invariant

Comment: Theo, could you accept your own answer, so that the robot doesn't regularly repost your question as unanswered?

Comment: @YCor Sure. Done.